# How can I clean table data using javascript empty method

Tags: javascript, html-table

In my code, I add an event listener to the pagination button. I can pass the page number to the function and set a new page number based on user input. Before changing the table data I want to clear the table. In this case, I am using `datatable.empty()` method but it gives me that the `datatable.empty` is not a function. Any idea how can I solve it?

```js
function pageButtons(pages) {
  var t = document.getElementById('test');
  for (var page = 1; page <= pages; page++) {
    //console.log(pages)
    t.innerHTML += '<button id=' + page + '>' + page + '</button>';

  }
  document.getElementById('test').addEventListener("click", function (event) {

    var newPageNumber = event.target.id;
    var datatable = document.getElementById('data1');
    state.page = newPageNumber;
    datatable.empty();
    console.log(state.page);
    buildTable();
  })

}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what your question is, so please add some context as to what the desired situation is.
`empty()` is indeed not a function of an html table. If you want to delete the table's content, use `datatable.innerHTML = ""`.